# Insert imagedata into MySQL database from XCode using PHP & JSON

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

How to insert/store images in MySQL database from XCode via PHP using JSON?

Comment: In xcode getting imagedata from Uiimageview this image i want to save it in mysql so that i m using PHP via Json parser.help me

Comment: 20954 bytes.I m storing employee details on server,via PHP from xcode except image all details are stored in MySql. i want to save employee image. how to send imagedata Through NsUrl to PHP and php code for insert image into mysql DB? help me..

Comment: how to  insert images as blob datatype into mysql DB.How to send images through json from xcode to insert.can anybody send php script?  help me...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the xcode, you do:

```
-(void) uploadImage: (UIImage *)image 
{
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 10);
        // setting up the URL to post to
        NSString *urlString = @"http://url.of.your.server/imagesupload.php";

        // setting up the request object now
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        /*
         add some header info now
         we always need a boundary when we post a file
         also we need to set the content type

         You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
         as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
         */
        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        /*
         now lets create the body of the post
         */
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"imagename.jpg\"\r\n",index] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(returnString);
}
```

From the PHP, you do:

```
function imageUpload()
{
// Make sure the user actually 
// selected and uploaded a file
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

      // Temporary file name stored on the server
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

      // Read the file 
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);


      // Create the query and insert
      // into our database.
      $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images ";
      $query .= "(image) VALUES ('$data')";
      $results = mysql_query($query, $link);

      // Print results
      print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
   print "No image selected/uploaded";
}

// Close our MySQL Link
mysql_close($link);
}
```