# How to upload image to SQL in Xcode?

Tags: php, iphone, sql, xcode

How to upload image to SQL in Xcode?  I have viewed past answers to this, but have several questions regarding these past answers.  Specifically, in the [following Q&A thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300935/insert-imagedata-into-mysql-database-from-xcode-using-php-json?answertab=active#tab-top), people suggest what the xcode and php files should look like.

So here are my follow up questions to that original post above:

1. I am assuming the code included for xcode is for the implementation file.  So what about the header file?  What should that look like?
2. How should the table in SQL be set up to accept the images/image data?

Answer (score 0):

1) That's the implementation file, you would declare your instance variables and methods in the header file.

2) The 'image' column in the above example would be a [Blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html):

```
CREATE TABLE 'images' ('id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 'image' BLOB NOT NULL);
```