# Sending NSData and NSString in the same POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I am trying to follow this [Insert imagedata into MySQL database from XCode using PHP & JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300935/insert-imagedata-into-mysql-database-from-xcode-using-php-json) answer to send a photo from my app to a MySQL database but I am confused as to how to add an `NSString` ID to reference to the `POST` body.

We have the following to create the body which gets the image data:

```
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"imagename.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

How might I send additional information such as a text ID within the same post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the whole code to post data along with Imagedata and string.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"imagename.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:@"<YOUR TEXT>" forKey:@"<KEY>"];

    [body appendData:[self createFormData:dict withBoundary:boundary]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);


- (NSData*)createFormData:(NSDictionary*)myDictionary withBoundary:(NSString*)myBounds
{
    NSMutableData *myReturn = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSArray *formKeys = [myDictionary allKeys];
    for (int i = 0; i < [formKeys count]; i++) {
        [myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",myBounds] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@",[formKeys objectAtIndex:i],[myDictionary valueForKey:[formKeys objectAtIndex:i]]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
    return myReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = body;
[request setValue:@"someValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"someField"];
```