# ios - Send image with other parameters by POST method

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-uploading

I have written a code to add item by user in web and its working fine.. now in that I want to add another  parameter i.e. an image.. i am not being able to do so.. my code is

```
NSString *posturslString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ToDo_Item=%@&ToDo_Date=%@&AddedBy=%i",self.ToDo_Item, [dateformatter stringFromDate:self.ToDo_Date],self.AddedBy];
NSString *postData = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:posturslString];


[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


[request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];

self.receivedData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSError * error;
NSDictionary *user = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];

NSNumber *successNumber =  [user objectForKey:@"success"];
success = [successNumber integerValue];
```

How can i send image i.e. a nsdata

```
NSData *png=UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.itemImage.image);
```

along with my other parameters. Help please.

Comment: Please refer this link: [Post data along with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662658/sending-nsdata-and-nsstring-in-the-same-post/32719056#32719056)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your image in **base64Encoded**

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImage, 1.0);
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
NSString *encodedString2 = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes( NULL,  (CFStringRef)base64String,    NULL,   CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),   kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

and add image same as your other keywords

```
NSString *posturslString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ToDo_Item=%@&ToDo_Date=%@&AddedBy=%i&image=%@",self.ToDo_Item, [dateformatter stringFromDate:self.ToDo_Date],self.AddedBy,encodedString2];
```

**Note : -**  Also need to implements on server side conversion of image **base64Encoded**

Comment: Thankyou.. atleast I got a start.. will comeback after trying to implement it.. :)

Comment: your answer worked fine for me.. and i did decode image string in server to save image.. :)

Comment: @Jogendra.Com Why do I need to percentage encode if I have base64String already created??